# Multiple Language Website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to have two languages on my website. Dutch and English.  I already have the English and the Dutch website in the "en" and "nl" folders in my root.

How or what would be the best way to redirect them? .htaccess or PHP.  And can you tell me how?

Comment: "Redirect them"...? Redirect what where based on what?

Comment: Please, please do not do something like, cookie{lang=en|nl} and in php: lang = getCookie("lang"), pathToPage = '/application/'.lang.'/path/to/page'. Because is prone to directory traversal and it's awful :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

htaccess seems to me to be so much easier. With php you would have to do an auto_prepend file I'm guessing. Another thing to keep in mind is to use the exact same page, so pick a language and use that for the url....ie en/about_us.html and nl/about_us.html the reason being is cause then google can figure out which pages are the same, but different languages. In terms of the rewrite if you have the folders in place then I don't see what you need a rewrite for. Will you please give me more information. Whenever I make a multilingual site my controllers are the same (in an mvc environment of course) and I just have two different views. In that case it'd be a rewrite like this

```
RewriteRule en/(.*).html /$1.php?language=en
RewriteRule nl/(.*).html /$1.php?language=nl

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE} ^(en)
RewriteRule ^[^en/](.*) /en/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE} ^(nl)
RewriteRule ^[^nl/](.*) /nl/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: The page names are indeed the same. I did that on purpose. I only want my customers to get send to the correct language automaticly. I'm using cloudflare. Maybe that will simplyfy things.

Comment: Ah then you'll want to do something like this: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header where it looks at the $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] to figure out the language. In that case it'd be php doing the work in an auto_prepend.

Comment: I prefer htacces. Do you have a website that explains that?

Comment: I see you have this in there: /$1.php?language=en

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is...the $1 means take w/e is in the () and put it there and I put ?language=en so your php file can use that variable to figure out what language it is.

Comment: I mean, what does this portion do?

RewriteRule en/(.*).html /$1.php?language=en
RewriteRule nl/(.*).html /$1.php?language=nl

Comment: Depending on your setup you may not need it. Its only needed if you have one php controller to handle both languages for example it'll do this: en/about_us.html to about_us.php?language=en and nl/about_us.html to about_us.php?language=nl

Comment: I wont use PHP with this. Only Htaccess if possible.

Comment: Then delete the first two lines

Comment: And how can I chnage it so that whenever the person is not Dutch, it gets redirected to english?

Comment: have a language selector on the page go to the english url.